# Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array. - no underfined symbolic variables

Tags: matlab

This is freaking me out, especially since it worked before. My code is this:

```
%Print the equations
fprintf('did: 0=%s\n',char(vpa(eval(did))));
fprintf('diq: 0=%s\n',char(vpa(eval(diq))));
%Print the parameter values
fprintf('m=%0.5f\n',m);
fprintf('iq=%0.5f\n',iq);
%Solve the qeuations
[L, R] = solve(did==0,diq==0,L,R);
fprintf('L=%s\n',char(vpa(eval(L))));
%Print the actual value
fprintf('L=%0.5f',double(eval(L)));
```

Of course, some things are defined earlier. But it doesn't matter, the output is pretty clear. I removed decimal precision for the question.

```
did: 0=0.33/L - (0.75*R)/L + 42.74
diq: 0=0.94/L - (0.68*R)/L - (20.94*m)/(L*iq) - 47.26
m=0.02
iq=0.68
L=0.0075 - (0.24*m)/iq
```

As you can see, the L is not fully calculated. Even though `m` and `iq` re defined and have values `0.02` and `0.68` respectively. And because of this, `double(eval(L))` prints error and stops me from continuing with my work:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.

If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.

Error in sym/double (line 702)
        Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Error in linearization (line 62)
fprintf('L=%0.5f',double(eval(L)));
```

I don't understand. Why are the `m` and `iq` values though I defined them as double?

Comment: Your code is not runnable. Please provide [runnable code that replicates this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what you're *actually* doing and let us better help you. Where did you define `m` and `iq` as doubles? Before or after `L=0.0075 - (0.24*m)/iq`? It looks like you also defined them as symbolic variables as well - if so, where did you substitute in the numeric values in the expression for `L`?

Comment: I'll try to come up with more code. But particularly your question *Before or after* has an obvious answer - you can see the debug info `m=0.02` *before* the `solve`.